# Blocking ssh bruteforcers with ufw

Tags: ssh, ufw

I want to block SSH brute force attacks using ufw.

Here is the code to block them:

Citing ["The Hail Mary Cloud And The Lessons Learned: BSDCan"](https://home.nuug.no/%7Epeter/hailmary2013/), it could be done:

- By pf:

  ```
  table <bruteforce> persist
  block quick from <bruteforce>
  pass inet proto tcp to $int_if:network port $tcp_services \
        keep state (max-src-conn 100, max-src-conn-rate 15/5, \
         overload <bruteforce> flush global)
  ```
- By iptables

  ```
  sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
  sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 15 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
  ```

I wonder if there is an equivalent to ufw or do I have to include iptables code in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`?

Please, don't advice me about sshguard or something else.

(Anyway, according to [FreeBSD manual](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/firewalls/#pftut-overload), even in IPtables, we cannot stop slow bruteforcers.)

Comment: you mean like using the `limit` option in [ufw](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/ufw/ufw.8.en.html#limit)

Comment: You may want to look into things like `fail2ban`. OpenSSH has server settings for that as well.

Comment: As @Stéphane Chazelas already mentioned, it is one of the best and simplest tools for that purpose, not only for SSH but also for DoS, DDoS, and so on.

Comment: Change the port to some high number (and use `fail2ban`). Removes 100% of all random brute force attacks.